# What does machdep stand for in sysctl machdep.cpu?

Tags: cpu

Trying to learn about the hardware configuration of my mac, I came accross the sysctl utility that has the very information *machdep* module. Just wondered if anyone know what it referred to, i.e. something with machine, detail, processor for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"machdep" stands for "machine dependent" as you can see in a comment in the [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software) code Apple has provided at [Makefile.template](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-344.49/iokit/conf/Makefile.template.auto.html).

```
#
#  Theses macros are filled in by the config program depending on the
#  current configuration.  The MACHDEP macro is replaced by the
#  contents of the machine dependent makefile template and the others
#  are replaced by the corresponding symbol definitions for the
#  configuration.
#
```

You can find lots of machine dependent information for your particular system with `sysctl machdep` or [sysctl machdep.cpu](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/os-x/machdep_cpu.php) for information on the [Central Processing Unit (CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit)) or you can have the utility display just a particular bit of information for the CPU by further narrowing what you want sysctl to display, e.g. `sysctl machdep.cpu.brand_string`. E.g.:

```
$ sysctl machdep.cpu.brand_string
machdep.cpu.brand_string: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4870HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz
```